# Как открыть часть файла в питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Смотрите, у меня есть файл длинной в 3-4 миллиона строк теста, мне нужно скопировать тест с 1 миллионной строки до 1.2 миллионной строки в другой файл, но открывать его нельзя, ибо тогда выйдет ошибка MemoryError

Если кто-то сможет помогите!

Comment: Открывать можно, только не считывайте весь файл сразу. Используйте `file.seek(pos)` чтобы сместить указатель чтения в позицию *pos* открытого файла, потом считайте нужные 200k строк. Только учтите, что `file.seek(1000)` переместит указатель на 1000й символ, а **не** на 1000ю строку. Также можно использовать `for line in file`, *line* будет принимать поочередно. Можно пропустить миллион итераций, потом считать следующие  200k итераций и записать данные в другой файл

Comment: хорошо как отодвинуть курсор файла в определённую сторону понял а как его остоновить через 200к строк

Comment: Смотрите измененный комментарий выше

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
start = 1_000_000
end = 1_200_000

with open('file1.txt') as file, open('file2.txt', 'w') as out:
    for i, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if i > end:
            break
        if i >= start:
            out.write(f'{line}\n')
```